# Java String array created inside loop

Tags: java

I have a question regarding the differences of the following codes:

```
Vector v = new Vector();
String [] str_arr = new String[3];

for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
   str_arr[0] = "A";
   str_arr[1] = "B";
   str_arr[2] = "C";            
   v.add(str_arr);
}
System.out.println(v.size());  //answer 3
```

Versus

```
Vector v = new Vector();


for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
   String [] str_arr = new String[3];
   str_arr[0] = "A";
   str_arr[1] = "B";
   str_arr[2] = "C";            
   v.add(str_arr);
}
System.out.println(v.size());  //answer 3
```

The only difference between both codes is, for the second one, string array is created inside the loop.

Both the codes produce same result, but i want to know what is the difference between these two.

Comment: In the second code snippet you creating the array 3 times - that means, the performance is lower

Comment: Don't use `Vector`, it isn't useful in 99% cases. It's a deprecated collection

Comment: @coolguy Except that it's not deprecated, and it's faster than a synchronized ArrayList.

Comment: @coolguy which collection you suggest me to use? im using java 1.4.2

Comment: @JohnE. I think you have it backwards. `Vector` is synchronized (at least since Java 1.5). `ArrayList` is not. You are correct that is not deprecated, but its use is discouraged when thread safety is not an issue.

Comment: @JohnE. well, yes, it's not annotated as deprecated. But still there are very few cases when it's justified to use `Vector`.
@user3172596 if you don't need to care about multi-thread environment it's usually right to use `ArrayList`. Btw are there any reasons you use such an old version of java? If no, it's better to update, ofc.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom I do not have is backwards. I purposely said that as I was talking about `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());`

Comment: @JohnE. Ok, fair point. But this post isn't about a multithreaded problem. It didn't occur to me that you'd sync-wrap a perfectly good unsynchronized collection just to say that it's slower that way. So yes, you do not have it backwards. My bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two snippets don't produce the same result. The first snippet adds the same array object 3 times to the Vector. The second snippet adds three different array objects to the Vector.

The results may seem the same, since all three arrays in the second snippet contain the same values.

If you'd change the assignment from

```
str_arr[0] = "A";
str_arr[1] = "B";
str_arr[2] = "C";
```

to

```
str_arr[0] = "A" + i;
str_arr[1] = "B" + i;
str_arr[2] = "C" + i;
```

You'd see that in the first snippet, the all the arrays in the Vector contain `[A2,B2,C2]`, since there's just one array that's getting overwritten.

On the other hand, the second snippet would produce a Vector that contains three different arrays - `[A0,B0,C0]`,`[A1,B1,C1]`,`[A2,B2,C2]`.

Comment: Perhaps you can give a small example of how this result can be observed? I.e. getting the first element from `v` and modifying it, will also modify the second and third element in `v` for the first code fragment.

Comment: @Eran thanks, sorry i was overlook, just looking at the size but not the content, thanks for the example.

Answer (score 2):

In the second version, the `String[]` goes out of scope at the end of each iteration. This means that you can't access it elsewhere. After the loop, the variable no longer exists. You also don't keep the value between iterations.

**EDIT**: The array itself still exists, as the vector keeps a strong reference to it.

However, there are some redundancy issues in your code.

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
   str_arr[0] = "A"; //all
   str_arr[1] = "B"; //of this
   str_arr[2] = "C"; //is redundant  
   v.add(str_arr);
}
```

Here (first version), you assign the same values to the array each iteration even though the variable still exists from one iteration to another, so you don't need most of the body

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom Thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Though the output will be the same, the state of your application will be different at the last line of both programs.

On the first, your heap will have only one array of Strings, and on the second it will have three.

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet will be a little faster than second snippet (tack less Memory and process)
because it implement the array once and update it's values in each loop 
but in the second snippet it's implement new array and register an address for it in each loop